# Stationary wave in a string

Tags: waves

When a stationary wave is generated in a string meanwhile if the tension in the string is also increased, what will be the effect on the speed of standing wave in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you asked this question, I think you don't know this equation
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{F} {\rho}}$$
where $\rho$ is mass per unit length, $v$ is velocity and here we can also think of $F$ like tension.